# How to put an object property in a variable?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var info = [
  {'user': 'person1','location': "NY"},
  {'user': 'person2','location': "NJ"},
  {'user': 'person3','location': "NC"}
];

var text="";


for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    text+='<div id="box" onclick="alertMe()">'+ info </div>';
}


function alertMe(){
  var val = info[location];
    alert(val);
}
```

This is focused on the `function alertMe()` part. I'm trying to put each location in one variable so when the user clicks on one, it will show an alert with the specific location.

Comment: Does your code make sense to you?

Comment: `info["location"]`, not `info[location]`

Comment: @GetSet I removed a lot of wingdings just to simplify it. When you click on a user/location pair, I want it to give an alert of the specific location you just clicked. Something is wrong with my `function alertMe(){`, syntax or method are bad. I'm out of ideas

Comment: @Azametzin that doesn't work, it alerts "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things that are not going to work with your code.

- The variable `location` is not defined.
- If you are trying to access the property `location` or your object, it might not work that way because `info` is an array. You could access `info` like so `info[0]` but not via the key `location` since it does not exist.
- From what I undestand, you want to show the currently clicked location. Your `alertMe` function has no way to know which location has been clicked.
- Not a problem but a suggestion, you might want to use let or const rather than val, [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/5784924).
- You are never adding your HTML string to the DOM, so nothing is appearing.
- You are missing a `'` in your string.
- You are trying to show the variable `info` in the tag `div` in your html, yet `info` is an array of objects.

With that in mind, here is a revised version of your code. Please try to understand what's going on rather than copy pasting this into your project.

```js
var info = [
  {'user': 'person1','location': "NY"},
  {'user': 'person2','location': "NJ"},
  {'user': 'person3','location': "NC"}
];

let text = "";


for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    const currentLocation = info[i];
    text+= `<div id="box" onclick="alertMe(${i})">${currentLocation.location}</div>`;
}

document.write(text)


function alertMe(index){
  const val = info[index].location;
  alert(val);
}
```

In this snippet, you can see that i've replace a few things.

- The `alertMe` function now take an index as an argument. Which will represent the index being clicked.
- I'm creating a new variable in my `for` loop for the current info element.
- I'm using this new variable to print the location.
- I'm accessing the clicked location via it's index rather than the innexisting `location` variable.
- I've replaced your string building with string template. Not necessary but cool.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because you're trying to access a property of an object in an array.

if you had:

```
const info = {'user': 'person1','location': "NY"}
```

then `info['location']` would work.
The way you have it you need to point to the relevant item of the array first:

```
    var info = [
      {'user': 'person1','location': "NY"},
      {'user': 'person2','location': "NJ"},
      {'user': 'person3','location': "NC"}
    ];

let myLocation = info[0]['location']
```

where 0 is the index of tfirst element of the array.